# Add new attachment actions in thunderbird

Tags: macos, mac, file-management, thunderbird

is it possible in thunderbird 3 to add new action for different types of attachments?

For instance, I receive a file with extension .xyz and I want to specify which program I need to use to open this file when I clicjh on the attachment

thanks

PD: I am jusing thunderbird 3 on mac os x

Answer (score 0):

While playing around I was surprised there is no way to add a new item via the gui. I did some digging tho and read through [this](http://kb.mozillazine.org/MimeTypes.rdf). Which then gave me the idea that I tested and works. You can copy over your MimeTypes.rdf from firefox to thunderbird. Which gives you some basic items listed and as well a working example on how to add more.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up renaming the TB3 MimeTypes.rdf to .bak and then copied my old TB2 MimeTypes.rdf file to the TB3 directory.  Works for all the files input before.  I can edit any on the list, but it looks like I cannot add new ones.